# Excluding data in KQL SLA charts

Tags: azure, powershell, alerts, kql

We are showing SLA charts for URLs, VPN and VMs for that if there is any planned scheduled maintenance we want to exclude that timings in KQL SLA charts as its known downtime.

We are disabling Alerts via powershell during this time we are passing below columns to Loganalytics custom table.

```
     "resourcename": "$resourcename",
     "Alertstate": "Enabled",
     "Scheduledmaintenance" : "stop",
     "Environment" : "UAT",
     "timestamp": "$TimeStampField",

    Now we want to use join condition SLA charts queries  with custom table data and exclude the time range in SLA charts during scheduled maintenance.

    Adding query as per request
    ---------------------------

    url_json_CL
    | where Uri_s contains "xxxx"
    | extend Availablity = iff(StatusCode_d ==200,1.000,0.000)
    | extend urlhit = 1.000
    | summarize PassCount = sum(Availablity), TestCount = sum(urlhit) by Uri_s ,ClientName_s
    | extend AVLPERCENTAGE = ((PassCount / TestCount ) * 100)
    | join kind=leftouter 
(  scheduledmaintenance2_CL
     | where ResourceName_s == "VMname" 
     | where ScheduledMaintenance_s == "start" 
     | extend starttime = timestamp_t)
     on ClientName_s
    | join kind= leftouter
     (scheduledmaintenance2_CL
     | where ResourceName_s == "VMname" 
     | where ScheduledMaintenance_s == "stop" 
     | extend stoptime = timestamp_t )
     on ClientName_s
     | extend excludedtime=stoptime - starttime  
     | project ClientName_s, ResourceName_s, excludedtime, AVLPERCENTAGE , Uri_s 
     | top 3 by  ClientName_s  desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform cross-resource log queries in Azure Monitor

1. Using Application Insights explorer we can query Log analytics workspace custom tables as well.

`workspace("/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/workspacename").Event | count`

2. Using Log Analytics logs explorer you can query the Application Insights Availability Results

`app("applicationinsightsinstancename").availabilityResults`

You can use any of the above options to query the required tables and join the tables. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/joins) documentation on joins.

[Additional documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can also upvote for a feature request on same lines in App Insights for planned downtime. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-monitor-alert-management/suggestions/16792825-there-should-be-a-maintanance-mode-feature-in-app

Comment: Thanks fo the reply ..nope this will not help at all

Comment: Can you please help share the query you are using to join the tables or steps you are following to fetch the SLA charts. Which might help me to better understand the problem you are running into. Thanks

Comment: we have one custom table which contains URLs running in 1 VM, we have created a dashboard by showing SLA for that URLs, when there is any secheduled maintainance client is aware of that maintainance so assume downtime is 1 hour in that virtual machine when we select SLA chats of 24hrs it has to exclude that 1 hour downtime and show it as 100% up for that we are passing schedule maintaince start time and stoptime to different custom table by joining both we have to exclude that time